# Проблемы сбором данных MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Есть такая коллекция **Description**:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Description { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

Есть такой простой шаблон данных одним котролом **TextBox** :

```
<!--Описание товара-->
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="6" >
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Description}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBox  Style="{StaticResource  BaseTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" Tag="Введите описание товара" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                        <Button
                             Margin="4"
                             Command="{Binding AddDescription}"
                             Content="Добавить описание товара"
                             Style="{StaticResource ButtonAdd}" />
                    </StackPanel>
```

Каманда **AddDescription**

```
        public ICommand AddDescription
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    Description.Add(" ");  
                });
            }
        }
```

**Проблема**:Команда **AddDescription** простая простая добавляет пустые **TextBox**,когда пользователь вводит данные они не сохраняться в коллекции Description.
Я не знаю как правильно привязаться к данным чтобы они изменяются(сохраняется).
Задумка такая я добавляю 4 пустых **TextBox** пользователь вводит данные если ему не достаточно контролов 4 он нажимать на кнопку и добавляет еще 1.

Comment: Определите для начала в чем проблема, выполняется ли у вас команда? Привязывается что либо другое? Что за `offer`? Дайте нам минимальный самодостаточный пример, ибо пока не очень понятно что именно у вас не работает.

Comment: Команда выполняться почему ей не выполняться,в модели Offer находиться коллекция Description.Проблема когда я пишу в TextBox данные  не сохрняться в Description.

Comment: А где у него привязка?

Comment: В том проблема к чему привязался просто коллекция строк(ObservableCollection<string>),Text="{Binding}"-выдает ошибку.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Ошибка:Двухстороннее связывание требует Path или XPath. Я делаю так Text="{Binding Path }" данные коллекция не получает.

Comment: Либо `Text="{Binding Path=.}"` (точка), либо `Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"`. Ну а вообще я советую вам создать класс, который будет хранить в себе текст и другую информацию.

Comment: Я пробовал 2 варианта не один не работает.Как вариант можно создать класс(Модель) 1 свойством типа string.Я понял проблема в том тип string не следит за изменением свойства.

Comment: Если изменение идет из UI, то следить там не за чем, а вот если изменение идет из кода, то да, следить надо (INPC). Вы как проверяете, изменилось значение или нет? Может вы держите фокус на TextBox и пытаетесь дождаться изменений? Если да, то по умолчанию свойство меняется только тогда, когда фокус с контрола уйдет.

Comment: У меня  должны изменения идти UI(View) из  контролера TextBox когда пользователь вводит туда данные  изменение не происходят.Я изначально делаю  4 контролера тоесть в коллекцию строк добавляю 4 пустых строк Description.Add(" "); но когда пишу в TextBox изменения не происходят. Я думаю отдельный класс сделать реализацией (INPC) ObservableCollection<SameClass>.

Comment: Тут скорей всего дело в том, что у вас нет как таковых свойств. Привязка работает только со свойствами, имеющие get и set, если их нет, то привязка либо вовсе не работает, либо ставиться односторонний режим. Так что да, лучше заменить `string` на `Class`, который будет содержать в себе `public string Text { get; set; }`.

Comment: Cпасибо вам,вам за потраченное время.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DescriptionModel**

```
class DescriptionModel:ChangeProperty
    {
        string text { get; set; }
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set 
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        public DescriptionModel() { }
        
        public DescriptionModel(string text)
        {
            Text = text;
        }

    }
```

**Descriptions**

```
 public ObservableCollection<DescriptionModel> Descriptions { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DescriptionModel>();
```

**Привязка данных**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="6" >
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding offer.Descriptions}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Style="{StaticResource  BaseTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" Tag="Введите описание товара" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                        <Button
                             Margin="4"
                             Command="{Binding AddDescription}"
                             Content="Добавить описание товара"
                             Style="{StaticResource ButtonAdd}" />
                    </StackPanel>
```