# Генерация файла Xml

Tags: c#, xml, mvvm

Пасирую данные из файла и записую модель и делаю измения:Удаляю,дабавляю продукты.

**Модель SellerModel**

```
class SellerModel : ChangeProperty
    {
        string name { get; set; }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        string сompany { get; set; }
        public string Company
        {
            get { return сompany; }
            set
            {
                сompany = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Company");
            }
        }
        string url { get; set; }
        public string Url
        {
            get { return url; }
            set
            {
                url = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Url");
            }
        }
        string date { get; set; }
        public string Date
        {
            get { return date; }
            set
            {
                date = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Date");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> Сategories { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<CurrencyModel> Currencies { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<OfferModel> Offers { get; set; }


        public SellerModel()
        {
            Сategories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryModel>();
            Currencies = new ObservableCollection<CurrencyModel>();
            Offers = new ObservableCollection<OfferModel>();
        }

    }
```

**OfferModel**

```
class OfferModel:ChangeProperty
    {
        string url { get; set; }
        public string Url
        {
            get { return url; }
            set
            {
                url = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Url");
            }
        }

        decimal price { get; set; }
        public decimal Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set
            {
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Price");
            }
        }

        string currencyId { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyId
        {
            get { return currencyId; }
            set
            {
                currencyId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrencyId");
            }
        }

        int categoryId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId
        {
            get { return categoryId; }
            set
            {
                categoryId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CategoryId");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Picture { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
       
        string name { get; set; }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        string vendor { get; set; }
        public string Vendor
        {
            get { return vendor; }
            set
            {
                vendor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Vendor");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<DescriptionModel> Descriptions { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DescriptionModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<ParamModel> Param { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ParamModel>();
       
        int stock_quantity { get; set; }
        public int Stock_quantity
        {
            get { return stock_quantity; }
            set
            {
                stock_quantity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Stock_quantity");
            }
        }

        bool аvailable { get; set; }
        public bool Available
        {
            get { return аvailable; }
            set
            {
                аvailable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Available");
            }
        }

        int id { get; set; }
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

        public OfferModel(){}
        public OfferModel(string url, decimal price, string currencyId, int categoryId, string name, string vendor, int stock_quantity, bool available, int id)
        {
            Url = url;
            Price = price;
            CurrencyId = currencyId;
            CategoryId = categoryId;
            Name = name;
            Vendor = vendor;
            Stock_quantity = stock_quantity;
            Available = available;
            Id = id;
        }

    }
```

**DescriptionModel**

```
class DescriptionModel:ChangeProperty
    {
        string text { get; set; }
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set 
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        public DescriptionModel() { }
        
        public DescriptionModel(string text)
        {
            Text = text;
        }

    }
```

**Файл XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="2018-05-23 12:00">
    <shop>
        <name>Кальченко Юрий</name>
        <company>ГАЛС-С</company>
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/</url>
        <currencies>
            <currency id="UAH" rate="1" />
        </currencies>
        <categories>
            <category id="1">Солнечные электростанции</category><!--Автономный инвертор ХТ (1.5кВт-10.0кВт)--> 
            <category id="2">Источники бесперебойного питания</category>
            <category id="3">Измерительная техника</category><!--MPPT Контроллер заряда ИМПУЛЬС-3010S)-->
            <category id="4">Пускозарядные устройства</category>
        </categories>
        <offers>
            <offer available="true" id="3001">
                <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx1-online.php</url>
                <price>6720</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>2</categoryId>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
                <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX1)</name>
                <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
                <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
                <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">12V</param>
                <param name="Мощность, кВт">0.5 кВт</param>
                <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">0.8 кВт</param>
                <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 50 А</param>
                <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
                <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
                <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
            </offer>
            <offer available="true" id="3002">
                <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx2-12-online.php</url>
                <price>11040</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>2</categoryId>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
                <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-12)</name>
                <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
                <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
                <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">12V</param>
                <param name="Мощность, кВт">1.0 кВт</param>
                <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">1.5 кВт</param>
                <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 90 А</param>
                <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
                <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
                <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
            </offer>
            <offer available="true" id="3003">
                <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx2-online.php</url>
                <price>11040</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>2</categoryId>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
                <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-24)</name>
                <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
                <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
                <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">24V</param>
                <param name="Мощность, кВт">1.3 кВт</param>
                <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">1.7 кВт</param>
                <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 50 А</param>
                <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
                <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
                <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
            </offer>
            <offer available="true" id="3004">
                <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx2-online-48v.php</url>
                <price>11040</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>2</categoryId>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
                <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-48)</name>
                <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
                <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
                <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">48V</param>
                <param name="Мощность, кВт">1.4 кВт</param>
                <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">1.7 кВт</param>
                <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 40 А</param>
                <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
                <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
                <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
            </offer>
            <offer available="true" id="3005">
                <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx3-24v-online.php</url>
                <price>19920</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>2</categoryId>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
                <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX3-24)</name>
                <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
                <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
                <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">24V</param>
                <param name="Мощность, кВт">2.2 кВт</param>
                <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">13.6 кВт</param>
                <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 90 А</param>
                <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
                <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
                <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
            </offer>
            <offer available="true" id="3006">
                <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx3-online.php</url>
                <price>19020</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>2</categoryId>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
                <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX3-48)</name>
                <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
                <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
                <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">48V</param>
                <param name="Мощность, кВт">2.2 кВт</param>
                <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">13.6 кВт</param>
                <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 50 А</param>
                <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
                <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
                <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
            </offer>

            <offer available="true" id="3006">
                <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx3-online.php</url>
                <price>19020</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>4</categoryId>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
                <name>ggg (MX3-48)</name>
                <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
                <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
                <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">48V</param>
                <param name="Мощность, кВт">2.2 кВт</param>
                <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">13.6 кВт</param>
                <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 50 А</param>
                <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
                <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
                <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
            </offer>
        </offers>
    </shop>
</yml_catalog>
```

Проблема:
Нужно все данные из  **Модели SellerModel** записать в сгенерированный файл и сохранить куда пользователь хочет.
Как я это выжу:

1.Переливаные данных из **Модели SellerModel** в новые классы для серезицазации(очень плохой вариант).

2.Как-то подставить данные в файл из  **Модели SellerModel** при генерации файла:

```
<name>${Name}</name>
```

Как должен выглядеть сгенерированный файл пример внизу,он выглядит как старый но с новыми данными и другая дата генерации `date="2018-05-23 12:00"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="Указывает дату и время генерации или изменения XML">
    <shop>
        <name>Название магазина</name>
        <company>Наименование компании</company>
        <url>URL главной страницы существующего магазина.</url>
        <currencies>
            <currency id="Валюта" rate="1" />
        </currencies>
        <categories>
            <category id="Каждой категории присваиваться уникальный номер.">Список категорий магазина.</category>
        </categories>
        <offers>
            <offer available="указывает наличие товара" id="каждому предложению необходимо присвоить уникальный номер ">
                <url>URL главной страницы существующего магазина.</url>
                <price>Цена товара.</price>
                <currencyId>Валюта</currencyId>
                <categoryId>уникальный номер категории </categoryId>
                <picture>Ссылка на фото товара.</picture>
                <name>Короткое название магазина.</name>
                <vendor>Бренд-производитель товара.</vendor>
                <description><![CDATA[<p>Описание товара</p>]]></description>
                <param name="Характеристики">значение характеристики</param>
                <stock_quantity>Товар будет в наличии на сайте.</stock_quantity>
            </offer>
            
        </offers>
    </shop>
</yml_catalog>
```

**Результат**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="6/20/2020 2:56:36 PM">
  <shop>
    <name>Кальченко Гена</name>
    <company>ГАЛС-С</company>
    <url>http://www.leoton.ua/</url>
    <currencies>
      <currency id="UAH" rate="1" />
      <currency id="$" rate="2" />
    </currencies>
    <categories>
      <category id="1">Солнечные электростанции</category>
      <category id="2">Источники бесперебойного питания</category>
      <category id="3">Измерительная техника</category>
      <category id="4">Пускозарядные устройства</category>
      <category id="5">d</category>
    </categories>
    <offers>
      <offer available="true" id="13">
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx1-online.php</url>
        <price>6720</price>
        <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
        <categoryId>2</categoryId>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
        <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX1)</name>
        <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
        <description><![CDATA[<p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
<p>ON-Line</p>
<p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
<p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
<p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
<p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>
]]></description>
        <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">12V</param>
        <param name="Мощность, кВт">0.5 кВт</param>
        <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">0.8 кВт</param>
        <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 50 А</param>
        <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
        <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
        <stock_quantity>10</stock_quantity>
      </offer>
      <offer available="true" id="33">
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx2-12-online.php</url>
        <price>11040</price>
        <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
        <categoryId>1</categoryId>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/4343.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/3434.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/3434.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/3443.jpg</picture>
        <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-12)</name>
        <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
        <description><![CDATA[<p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
<p>ON-Line</p>
<p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
<p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
<p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
<p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>
]]></description>
        <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">30V</param>
        <param name="Мощность, кВт">4.0 кВт</param>
        <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">5.5 кВт</param>
        <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 93434 А</param>
        <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
        <param name="Гарантия">3 год</param>
        <stock_quantity>99</stock_quantity>
      </offer>
    </offers>
  </shop>
</yml_catalog
```

Comment: У вас русский язык не родной? Очень своебразно пишете текст.

Comment: Вывод чего бы то ни было в XML - это функция, которая не имеет отношения к MVVM вообще, ни к моделям MVVM. Я предпочитаю писать для этого отдельные классы и модели.

Comment: Как я понял написать отдельные классы подходящие под структуру файла и передать туда данные из Seller Model?

Comment: да, я бы сделал так. То есть 1) Написал бы модели для XML с данными, что я хочу сохранить в XML 2) Класс, который мапит MVVM модели на модели для XML, класс, который принимает модели для XML и выдает сериализованный Stream или String, и класс который принимает путь к файлу, Stream или String  и пишет этот Stream или String в файл

Comment: @Vladimir, Почему бы не использовать XSLT-преобразование для создания желаемого выходного файла XML?

Comment: @Yitzhak Khabinsky я  не знаю что это  XSLT,можете дать пример??

Comment: Покажите код, как вы из XML данные загружаете, я пока не понимаю, почему у вас не получается выполнить обратный процесс. Вы в курсе, что такое сериализация и десереализация?

Comment: @aepot да знаю что такое сериализация и десереализация.Если я не знал как я получил данные из XML файла?

Comment: Следовательно вы знаете, как их туда записать. Сериализация и десереализация это обратимые процессы, которые друг друга обращают.

Comment: @Vladimir, XSLT-преобразование будет обрабатывать входной XML-файл для генерации желаемого выходного XML-файла. Входной XML + XSLT = Выходной XML.

Comment: XSLT не нужен. Говорю это как человек, написавший множество трансформаций. Преобразование XML с помощью C# намного проще (и работает быстрее). И любой джуниор потом код поддерживать сможет.

Comment: Я написал классы специальные под мою задачу но есть проблема я ее расписал  внизу в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я просто покажу пример сериализации и десереализации.

Иду на сайт https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ - Xml2Csharp.com Converter. Вставляю туда, ваш XML, получаю почти готовый код классов.

Путем нескольких доработок, спустя 5 минут, получаю вполне рабочий код для хранения данных:

```csharp
[XmlRoot("currency")]
public class Currency
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("rate")]
    public string Rate { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("currencies")]
public class Currencies
{
    [XmlElement("currency")]
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("category")]
public class Category
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("categories")]
public class Categories
{
    [XmlElement("category")]
    public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("param")]
public class Param
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("offer")]
public class Offer
{
    private string _description;

    [XmlElement("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("price")]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("currencyId")]
    public string CurrencyId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("categoryId")]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("picture")]
    public List<string> Picture { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("vendor")]
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public XmlCDataSection Description
    {
        get => new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(_description);
        set => _description = value.Value;
    }
    [XmlElement("param")]
    public List<Param> Param { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("stock_quantity")]
    public int StockQuantity { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("available")]
    public string Available { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("offers")]
public class Offers
{
    [XmlElement("offer")]
    public List<Offer> Offer { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("shop")]
public class Shop
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("currencies")]
    public Currencies Currencies { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("categories")]
    public Categories Categories { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("offers")]
    public Offers Offers { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("yml_catalog")]
public class YmlCatalog
{
    [XmlElement("shop")]
    public Shop Shop { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Читать данные можно так

```csharp
YmlCatalog catalog;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("catalog.xml"))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YmlCatalog));
    catalog = (YmlCatalog)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
}
```

С данными можно работать

```csharp
foreach (Offer offer in catalog.Shop.Offers.Offer)
{
    Console.WriteLine(offer.Name);
}
```

Кажется, работает

```
Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX1)
Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-12)
Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-24)
Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-48)
Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX3-24)
Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX3-48)
ggg (MX3-48)
```

Писать в файл можно вот так

```csharp
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("catalog_out.xml"))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YmlCatalog));
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    serializer.Serialize(sw, catalog, ns);
}
```

Ну и вот "как есть" xml файл, записанный из данных в классах методом записи, показанным выше. Как говорится, найдите все отличия. :) Они есть, но на качество данных не влияют.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="2018-05-23 12:00">
  <shop>
    <name>Кальченко Юрий</name>
    <company>ГАЛС-С</company>
    <url>http://www.leoton.ua/</url>
    <currencies>
      <currency id="UAH" rate="1" />
    </currencies>
    <categories>
      <category id="1">Солнечные электростанции</category>
      <category id="2">Источники бесперебойного питания</category>
      <category id="3">Измерительная техника</category>
      <category id="4">Пускозарядные устройства</category>
    </categories>
    <offers>
      <offer available="true" id="3001">
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx1-online.php</url>
        <price>6720</price>
        <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
        <categoryId>2</categoryId>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
        <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX1)</name>
        <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
        <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
        <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">12V</param>
        <param name="Мощность, кВт">0.5 кВт</param>
        <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">0.8 кВт</param>
        <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 50 А</param>
        <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
        <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
        <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
      </offer>
      <offer available="true" id="3002">
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx2-12-online.php</url>
        <price>11040</price>
        <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
        <categoryId>2</categoryId>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
        <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-12)</name>
        <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
        <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
        <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">12V</param>
        <param name="Мощность, кВт">1.0 кВт</param>
        <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">1.5 кВт</param>
        <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 90 А</param>
        <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
        <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
        <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
      </offer>
      <offer available="true" id="3003">
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx2-online.php</url>
        <price>11040</price>
        <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
        <categoryId>2</categoryId>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
        <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-24)</name>
        <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
        <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
        <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">24V</param>
        <param name="Мощность, кВт">1.3 кВт</param>
        <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">1.7 кВт</param>
        <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 50 А</param>
        <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
        <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
        <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
      </offer>
      <offer available="true" id="3004">
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx2-online-48v.php</url>
        <price>11040</price>
        <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
        <categoryId>2</categoryId>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
        <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-48)</name>
        <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
        <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
        <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">48V</param>
        <param name="Мощность, кВт">1.4 кВт</param>
        <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">1.7 кВт</param>
        <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 40 А</param>
        <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
        <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
        <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
      </offer>
      <offer available="true" id="3005">
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx3-24v-online.php</url>
        <price>19920</price>
        <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
        <categoryId>2</categoryId>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
        <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX3-24)</name>
        <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
        <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
        <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">24V</param>
        <param name="Мощность, кВт">2.2 кВт</param>
        <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">13.6 кВт</param>
        <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 90 А</param>
        <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
        <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
        <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
      </offer>
      <offer available="true" id="3006">
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx3-online.php</url>
        <price>19020</price>
        <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
        <categoryId>2</categoryId>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
        <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX3-48)</name>
        <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
        <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
        <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">48V</param>
        <param name="Мощность, кВт">2.2 кВт</param>
        <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">13.6 кВт</param>
        <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 50 А</param>
        <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
        <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
        <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
      </offer>
      <offer available="true" id="3006">
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx3-online.php</url>
        <price>19020</price>
        <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
        <categoryId>4</categoryId>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
        <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
        <name>ggg (MX3-48)</name>
        <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
        <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
        <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">48V</param>
        <param name="Мощность, кВт">2.2 кВт</param>
        <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">13.6 кВт</param>
        <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 50 А</param>
        <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
        <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
        <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
      </offer>
    </offers>
  </shop>
</yml_catalog>
```

---

Отвечая на второй ваш вопрос, как сделать описание в CDATA в формате HTML по спецификации на [сайте магазина](https://sellerhelp.rozetka.com.ua/st/p/pricelist-requirements).

1. Модифицируйте `DescriptionModel`

```csharp
public class DescriptionModel : ChangeProperty
{
    private string text { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<string> features = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Features
    {
        get { return features; }
        set
        {
            features = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Features));
        }
    }

    public DescriptionModel() { }

    public DescriptionModel(string text, ObservableCollection<string> features)
    {
        Text = text;
        Features = features;
    }
}
```

Что я сделал: добавил список строк `Features`, он будет служить для генерации выходного HTML списка. Это вместо псевдо-точек в начале строк в вашем примере.

2. В `OfferModel` у вас есть коллекция

```csharp
public ObservableCollection<DescriptionModel> Descriptions { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DescriptionModel>();
```

просто замените ее на класс:

```csharp
public DescriptionModel { get; set; }
```

3. Вот пример добавления в нее данных.

```csharp
DescriptionModel decription = new DescriptionModel();
decription.Text = "ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.\r\nON-Line";
decription.Features.Add("Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования");
decription.Features.Add("Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры");
decription.Features.Add("Для газовых котлов всех типов");
decription.Features.Add("Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры");
```

`Text` Многострочный, каждую новую строку будем считать новым параграфом.

4. И теперь простое преобразование в HTML со списком, не используя внешние библиотеки, а просто вручную.

```csharp
private string DescriptionToHTML(DescriptionModel decription)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    foreach (string s in decription.Text.Split("\r\n"))
    {
        result += "<p>" + s + "</p>\r\n";
    }
    if (decription.Features?.Count > 0)
    {
        result += "<ul>\r\n";
        foreach (string s in decription.Features)
        {
            result += "<li>" + s + "</li>\r\n";
        }
        result += "</ul>";
    }
    return result.Trim();
}
```

И эту функцию можно так использовать:

```csharp
string html = DescriptionToHTML(decription);
```

5. И теперь можно загнать это в XML CDATA

```csharp
XmlCDataSection xmlDescription = new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(html);
```

Выходной HTML выглядит так:

```html
<p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
<p>ON-Line</p>
<ul>
<li>Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</li>
<li>Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</li>
<li>Для газовых котлов всех типов</li>
<li>Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</li>
</ul>
```

CDATA соответственно вот так

```xml
<![CDATA[<p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
<p>ON-Line</p>
<ul>
<li>Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</li>
<li>Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</li>
<li>Для газовых котлов всех типов</li>
<li>Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</li>
</ul>]]>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109589/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot---xml).

Comment: В некоторых товаров только <p> тег. Спасибо вам за потраченное время.

Comment: @Vladimir так не заполняйте коллецую `Features`, вносите только многострочный `Text`, и не будет списка `<ul>`, будет только `<p>`. Изучите код метода `DescriptionToHTML()`, доработайте под себя, если требуется.

Comment: Спасибо вы очень помогли мне.

Comment: Я посмотрел и понял  не получиться  заменить на `public DescriptionModel { get; set; }`  но я суть понял или можно заменить  но с делать   `public ObservableCollection<DescriptionModel> Descriptions { get; set; }`  в классе   `DescriptionModel` вот какие  у меня были  с привязкой:[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140994/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-mvvm](Проблемы сбором данных MVVM)

Comment: @Vladimir все получится, если постараться, и понять как это работает. И вы странно используете команды, те что по ссылке, у вас создается новая команда при обращении к ней. Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131736/wpf-listbox-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-mvvm/1131976#1131976), как я использую команды.

Comment: @Vladimir вам нужно понять, как это все работает, почитайте документацию ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern))

Comment: @aepot  Еще раз огромное спасибо вам за помощь,я все изучу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109607/discussion-between-vladimir-and-aepot).

Comment: @aepot: «Иду на сайт https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ - Xml2Csharp.com» — есть вроде проще способ: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u6KM.png