# Парсинг XML ответа со спецсимволами &lt; средствами SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

Есть ответ сервера со спецсимволами. Как парсить такого рода ответы?

```
<Text xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?&gt;
&lt;getCarNSIReply&gt;
&lt;car&gt;
&lt;carNumber value="29129426"/&gt;
&lt;carNSIDate value="20.05.2020 14:30:05"/&gt;
&lt;carResponse value="1"/&gt;
&lt;carTypeID value="40"/&gt;
&lt;carTypeCode value="20"/&gt;
&lt;carTypeName value="крытые"/&gt;
&lt;carAxles value="4"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerCountryCode value="643"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerCountryName value="РОССИЯ"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerTypeID value="1"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerTypeName value="Собственный"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerId value="352666"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerOKPO value="76396169"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerName value="Публичное акционерное общество &amp;quot;ТРАНСФИН-М&amp;quot;"/&gt;
&lt;carTonnage value="67"/&gt;
&lt;carWeightDep value="268"/&gt;
&lt;carTankType value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carVolume value="161"/&gt;
&lt;carArendatorID value="648579"/&gt;
&lt;carArendatorOKPO value="06087120"/&gt;
&lt;carArendatorName value="Общество с ограниченной ответственностью &amp;quot;ФТ Логистик&amp;quot;"/&gt;
&lt;carEndArendaDate value="30.06.2029 00:00:00"/&gt;
&lt;carYear value="2019"/&gt;
&lt;carTypeRepair value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carNextRepair value="04.06.2022 00:00:00"/&gt;
&lt;carBanned value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carSign value="3"/&gt;
&lt;carLength value="18.86"/&gt;
&lt;carRace value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carNorma value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carDateSob value="12.08.2019 00:00:00"/&gt;
&lt;carModel value="11-2135-01"/&gt;
&lt;carConsPark value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carTrustedOperatorID value="635766"/&gt;
&lt;carTrustedOperatorOKPO value="33977721"/&gt;
&lt;carTrustedOperator value="ООО &amp;quot;Кучуктерминал&amp;quot;"/&gt;
&lt;carKODS value="10613"/&gt;
&lt;carKODARNUM value="13137"/&gt;
&lt;carCN_SOBSTV_ID value="178"/&gt;
&lt;carTYPEV value="211"/&gt;
&lt;carMODEL_CODE value="2624"/&gt;
&lt;carPR_K value="1"/&gt;
&lt;carPR_K_NAME value="Наличие тех.паспорта"/&gt;
&lt;/car&gt;
&lt;car&gt;
&lt;carNumber value="29131398"/&gt;
&lt;carNSIDate value="15.06.2020 03:33:37"/&gt;
&lt;carResponse value="1"/&gt;
&lt;carTypeID value="40"/&gt;
&lt;carTypeCode value="20"/&gt;
&lt;carTypeName value="крытые"/&gt;
&lt;carAxles value="4"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerCountryCode value="643"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerCountryName value="РОССИЯ"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerTypeID value="1"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerTypeName value="Собственный"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerId value="550308"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerOKPO value="78961835"/&gt;
&lt;carOwnerName value="Общество с ограниченной ответственностью &amp;quot;РЕГИОН Групп Лизинг&amp;quot;"/&gt;
&lt;carTonnage value="66.7"/&gt;
&lt;carWeightDep value="271"/&gt;
&lt;carTankType value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carVolume value="165"/&gt;
&lt;carArendatorID value="646153"/&gt;
&lt;carArendatorOKPO value="03581196"/&gt;
&lt;carArendatorName value="Общество с ограниченной ответственностью &amp;quot;Успешная Команда &amp;quot;Русская Сталь&amp;quot;"/&gt;
&lt;carEndArendaDate value="10.02.2026 00:00:00"/&gt;
&lt;carYear value="2013"/&gt;
&lt;carTypeRepair value="1"/&gt;
&lt;carLastRepair value="13.02.2020 00:00:00"/&gt;
&lt;carNextRepair value="13.02.2022 00:00:00"/&gt;
&lt;carBanned value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carSign value="3"/&gt;
&lt;carLength value="18.84"/&gt;
&lt;carRace value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carNorma value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carDateSob value="09.04.2019 00:00:00"/&gt;
&lt;carModel value="11-1807-01"/&gt;
&lt;carConsPark value="0"/&gt;
&lt;carTrustedOperatorID value="662733"/&gt;
&lt;carTrustedOperatorOKPO value="06304155"/&gt;
&lt;carTrustedOperator value="ООО &amp;quot;УК &amp;quot;РС-транс&amp;quot;"/&gt;
&lt;carKODS value="171436"/&gt;
&lt;carKODARNUM value="173181"/&gt;
&lt;carCN_SOBSTV_ID value="178"/&gt;
&lt;carTYPEV value="211"/&gt;
&lt;carMODEL_CODE value="1231"/&gt;
&lt;carPR_K value="1"/&gt;
&lt;carPR_K_NAME value="Наличие тех.паспорта"/&gt;
&lt;/car&gt;
&lt;/getCarNSIReply&gt;
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не валидный XML, у него бардак с неймспейсами. И вообще, это выглядит как XML внутри другого XML. Я покажу, как распаковать.

Класс данных

```csharp
[XmlRoot("Text")]
public class PackedResponse
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Распаковка

```csharp
string text; // пусть строковая переменная text содержит ваш ответ от сервера

// ...

PackedResponse response;
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(text))
{
    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(sr))
    {
        reader.Namespaces = false;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PackedResponse));
        response = (PackedResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(response.Text);
```

Вывод в консоль.

```csharp
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<getCarNSIReply>
<car>
<carNumber value="29129426"/>
<carNSIDate value="20.05.2020 14:30:05"/>
<carResponse value="1"/>
<carTypeID value="40"/>
<carTypeCode value="20"/>
<carTypeName value="крытые"/>
<carAxles value="4"/>
<carOwnerCountryCode value="643"/>
<carOwnerCountryName value="РОССИЯ"/>
<carOwnerTypeID value="1"/>
<carOwnerTypeName value="Собственный"/>
<carOwnerId value="352666"/>
<carOwnerOKPO value="76396169"/>
<carOwnerName value="Публичное акционерное общество &quot;ТРАНСФИН-М&quot;"/>
<carTonnage value="67"/>
<carWeightDep value="268"/>
<carTankType value="0"/>
<carVolume value="161"/>
<carArendatorID value="648579"/>
<carArendatorOKPO value="06087120"/>
<carArendatorName value="Общество с ограниченной ответственностью &quot;ФТ Логистик&quot;"/>
<carEndArendaDate value="30.06.2029 00:00:00"/>
<carYear value="2019"/>
<carTypeRepair value="0"/>
<carNextRepair value="04.06.2022 00:00:00"/>
<carBanned value="0"/>
<carSign value="3"/>
<carLength value="18.86"/>
<carRace value="0"/>
<carNorma value="0"/>
<carDateSob value="12.08.2019 00:00:00"/>
<carModel value="11-2135-01"/>
<carConsPark value="0"/>
<carTrustedOperatorID value="635766"/>
<carTrustedOperatorOKPO value="33977721"/>
<carTrustedOperator value="ООО &quot;Кучуктерминал&quot;"/>
<carKODS value="10613"/>
<carKODARNUM value="13137"/>
<carCN_SOBSTV_ID value="178"/>
<carTYPEV value="211"/>
<carMODEL_CODE value="2624"/>
<carPR_K value="1"/>
<carPR_K_NAME value="Наличие тех.паспорта"/>
</car>
<car>
<carNumber value="29131398"/>
<carNSIDate value="15.06.2020 03:33:37"/>
<carResponse value="1"/>
<carTypeID value="40"/>
<carTypeCode value="20"/>
<carTypeName value="крытые"/>
<carAxles value="4"/>
<carOwnerCountryCode value="643"/>
<carOwnerCountryName value="РОССИЯ"/>
<carOwnerTypeID value="1"/>
<carOwnerTypeName value="Собственный"/>
<carOwnerId value="550308"/>
<carOwnerOKPO value="78961835"/>
<carOwnerName value="Общество с ограниченной ответственностью &quot;РЕГИОН Групп Лизинг&quot;"/>
<carTonnage value="66.7"/>
<carWeightDep value="271"/>
<carTankType value="0"/>
<carVolume value="165"/>
<carArendatorID value="646153"/>
<carArendatorOKPO value="03581196"/>
<carArendatorName value="Общество с ограниченной ответственностью &quot;Успешная Команда &quot;Русская Сталь&quot;"/>
<carEndArendaDate value="10.02.2026 00:00:00"/>
<carYear value="2013"/>
<carTypeRepair value="1"/>
<carLastRepair value="13.02.2020 00:00:00"/>
<carNextRepair value="13.02.2022 00:00:00"/>
<carBanned value="0"/>
<carSign value="3"/>
<carLength value="18.84"/>
<carRace value="0"/>
<carNorma value="0"/>
<carDateSob value="09.04.2019 00:00:00"/>
<carModel value="11-1807-01"/>
<carConsPark value="0"/>
<carTrustedOperatorID value="662733"/>
<carTrustedOperatorOKPO value="06304155"/>
<carTrustedOperator value="ООО &quot;УК &quot;РС-транс&quot;"/>
<carKODS value="171436"/>
<carKODARNUM value="173181"/>
<carCN_SOBSTV_ID value="178"/>
<carTYPEV value="211"/>
<carMODEL_CODE value="1231"/>
<carPR_K value="1"/>
<carPR_K_NAME value="Наличие тех.паспорта"/>
</car>
</getCarNSIReply>
```

Теперь это можно десереализовать как нормальный XML.

Comment: @romanegorov Что значит нормализовать? Я распаковал вам XML, его можно [десереализовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142385/373567) в класс с данными, как любой другой обычный XML.

Answer (score 0):

Предложу ещё более простой способ.

```
string text = "ответ сервера";

var xml = XElement.Parse(text);

var elem = XElement.Parse(xml.Value.Trim());

Console.WriteLine(elem);
```

Первым вызовом `XElement.Parse` получаем результат, в котором `&lt;` и `&gt;` заменены на `<` и `>`.

Вторым вызовом `XElement.Parse` парсим этот результат. Только нужно окружающие пробельные символы удалить.

Далее средствами linq to xml получаем значения:

```
var carNumber = elem.Element("car").Element("carNumber").Attribute("value").Value;

Console.WriteLine(carNumber); // 29129426
```