# Игнорировать строку при записи текста в файл

Tags: c#, unity3d, xml

В проекте на Unity имеется XML файл в который копируется нужный XML из Text Asset'a.
Т.к. данные хранятся в `Application.persistentDataPath` у меня есть метод на проверку наличия данного файла и его создания. Но в XML файле имеется атрибут `result`. Можно ли дописывать данный файл но с игнором атрибута и его значения?

XML файл:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<starsData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <level name="Game">
    <starCollect result="false">Collect a pineapple!!</starCollect>
    <starSave result="false">Save a fruit!!!</starSave>
    <escapeStar result="false">Escape a fruit!!</escapeStar>
  </level>
  <level name="Level02">
    <starCollect result="false">Collect a fruit</starCollect>
    <starSave result="false">Save a fruit</starSave>
    <escapeStar result="false">Save a fruit</escapeStar>
  </level>
</starsData>
```

Метод проверки:

```cs
public static void CheckForExists(TextAsset textAsset)
        {
            var path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/StarsData.xml";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                fs.Dispose();
                
            }
            File.WriteAllText(path, textAsset.text);
        }
```

Comment: Странно вы создаете файл, можно упростить до одной строки `File.Create(...)`. По поводу XML, вероятно вам нужно десеревюализовать данные, изменить, сериализовать обратно и записать в файл, примеров сериализации XML даже [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142385/373567) полно. Но может есть способ проще, я не знаком с Unity.

Comment: Почитайте про [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8) еще, надо либо конструкцию `try-finally` использовать, либо `using`.

Answer (score -1):

Так как текст является xml, можно его распарсить и удалить атрибут следующим образом:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;


var xml = XElement.Parse(textAsset.text);
xml.Descendants().Attributes("result").Remove();
xml.Save(path);
```