# Редактирование XML в заданном формате

Tags: c#, winforms

*Есть файл* **XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<specifications>
<s name="">

</s>
<s name="EV3">
<sg>КМ-01</sg>
<sg>КМ-02</sg>
<sg>КМ-03</sg>
<sg>КМ-04</sg>
<sg>КМ-05</sg>
<sg>КМ-06</sg>
<sg>КМ-07</sg>
<sg>КМП-01</sg>
  
</s>
<s name="WeDo">
<sg>КВ-01</sg>
<sg>КВ-02</sg>
<sg>КВ-03</sg>
<sg>КВ-04</sg>
<sg>КВ-05</sg>
<sg>КВ-06</sg>
</s>
<s name="PROG">
<sg>ПО-01</sg>
<sg>ПО-02</sg>
</s>
<s name="EL">
<sg></sg>
<sg></sg>
</s>
<s name="PE">
<sg>ПДК-01</sg>
<sg>ПДК-02</sg>
</s>
<s name="SPIKE">
<sg>СПК-01</sg>
<sg>СПК-02</sg>
</s>

</specifications>
```

Каким образом я могу *добавлять/удалять/изменять* элементы ***ИМЕННО В ТАКОМ*** виде файла

**P.S.** Мне известны более простые варианты работы с **xml**, но необходимо понять принцип работы такого формата

**P.P.S.** *я не сумел найти решение для моей задачи в сети*

***Благодарю заранее за ответы***

Comment: Может быть [десереализация и сериализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142385/373567) поможет

Comment: Принцип абсолютно такой же, как с любыми другими форматами: читаем xml в структуру данных, работаем со структурой данных (добавляем/изменяем/удаляем), сохраняем обратно в xml. В качестве структуры данных может выступать как типизированный набор классов (используем (де)сериализацию), так и любой из классов, специально созданных для работы с xml (XDocument/XElement в первую очередь).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, сам принцип работы то мне понятен. главная загвоздка у меня в том, как различить элементы при одинаковом названии субэлемента

Comment: Не надо их различать. Просто проходите по коллекции.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не могли бы вы дать пример, что-то никак не соображу

Comment: Я вам выше ссылку на пример кинул. Примернее некуда.