# Как записать в имя файла сохраняемого файла текст? C#

Tags: c#

Есть файл "C:\1.xml"

```
<measData>
<manElement usLa="LTF_51_C" />
<Info InfoId="726657">
  <granPeriod dur="0S" endTime="2021-02-13T" />
  <repPeriod dur="PT900S" />
  <Types>1526 748764 1548765 </Types>
```

Обрабатываю файл xml в C#.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\1.xml");
        IEnumerable<string> xmlLines = lines.Where(x => x.Contains("<Types>"));
        HashSet<string> xmlLinesHashSet = new HashSet<string>(xmlLines);
        string[] sorted = xmlLinesHashSet.ToArray();
        File.WriteAllLines("C:\\2.xml", sorted);
```

Получаю результат

```
<Types>1526 748764 1548765 </Types> <Types>1557 1526764 15265 </Types>
```

Так вот - хачу, что бы файл создавался не как я его назову "C:\2.xml", а брал названия из текста автоматом из строчки  и создавался вот так "C:\LTF_51_C.xml"

Comment: 1. XML где? 2. Где ваш код, которым вы достаете данные? 3. Где ваши вообще попытки? Или вы хотите, чтоб мы тут ванговали, гадая что там у вас не так? Поймите, что вы задаете первым попавшимся людям вопрос, которые не в курсе что у вас за проект, что вы умеете, что вам надо и кучу всего другого, вот вы сами поймете этот весь текс, не зная всего перечисленного мною? Я думаю, нет.

Comment: Поправил свой вопрос

Comment: Почему вы так криво читаете XML? Сейчас вот вы задали два вопроса и оба имеют одно решение, а именно - правильная работа с XML форматом, где вы без труда возьмете аттрибут `usLa`, получите все `Types` и так далее.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142385/373567