# Трансляция данных с помощью Webrequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

У меня есть страница https://mail.ru/#main и мне необходимо выводить только заголовки новостей. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как это сделать?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Да, все отлично работает. Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откройте [Mail.ru news](https://news.mail.ru/), прокрутите вниз, там в футере ссылки RSS, выберите нужную, дальше код:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string xml = await client.GetStringAsync("https://news.mail.ru/rss/91/");
    Console.WriteLine(xml);
}
```

и читайте [как парсить XML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142385/373567), примеров здесь много разных.

---

И да, `WebRequest` устарел, об этом написано даже в [его документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8#remarks), использовать надо `HttpClient`.

> **Важно!**
>
> Не рекомендуется использовать `WebRequest` или производные классы для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` класс.

Также специально для работы с RSS есть `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` Namespace - [документация .NET 5 Platform Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.syndication?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Comment: Специально для работы с RSS есть [Syndication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.syndication?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) namespace

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, добавил в ответ.