# Вывести неизвестный атрибут xml

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xml, linq

У меня есть xml файл

```
<Users>
<UserName>Человек1</UserName>
<UserPass>Пароль1</UserPass>
```

В нем хранится логин и пароль.

Логин, выводится в combobox

Там мы должны выбрать какой-то логин. И чтобы упростить задачу, скажу так...
В другую строку, нужно вывести его сопутствующий пароль. Как это сделать, понятия не имею. xml я наполнял с помощью linq.

```
void XMLRes()
    {
        foreach (XElement phoneElement in xdoc.Element("Users").Elements("Users"))
        {
            XElement companyElement = phoneElement.Element("UserName");
            XElement priceElement = phoneElement.Element("UserPass");

            if (companyElement != null && priceElement != null)
            {
                cmBoxUsers.Items.Add(companyElement.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста.. В класс лезть не хочу. Не совсем понимаю(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На всякий случай, пароли не хранят в открытом виде, не забывайте хешировать. И JSON лучше, легче и проще, чем XML.

Comment: Создайте модель данных, класс `Users`, заведите в нем 2 свойства `UserName` и `UserPass` и десереализуйте в массив. Операция настолько простая, что я удивлен, что вы не нашли решения. Я как минимум несколько раз их здесь постил. Например [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142385/373567). Не бойтесь использовать ООП.

Comment: Да, шифрование в релизе ставлю, когда все готово. Ну а если кроме класса, ничего нельзя, то ладно( Придется возвращаться и разбираться. Я класс то сделал. Но он только Записывает. А если внести новое значение, то файл перезаписывается. Оно и логично

Comment: Ну почему нельзя, можно, просто сложнее. Мне бы было лень.

Comment: @aepot здравствуйте. Не хотел бы засорять топик своими тупыми вопросами, но хотел бы узнать у вас. Я использовал библиотеку MaterialStyle, которая добавляет кнопки и т.п в стиле MaterialDesign, и все круто, но она очень криво работает в 7й винде. Вообще отврат. Все криво нарисовано. Возможно ли при узнавании версии ОС, заменять элементы? Хуже всего, смотрится Panel.Теней нет, вместо них треш. И как то автоматом заменить Material Panel на другую? Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнём с того, что `<UserPass>Пароль1</UserPass>` - это **элемент**, а не **атрибут**.

---

Я бы предложил следующую структуру xml:

```
<Users>
  <User>
    <Name>Человек1</Name>
    <Pass>Пароль1</Pass>
  </User>
  <User>
    <Name>Человек2</Name>
    <Pass>Пароль2</Pass>
  </User>
</Users>
```

Элемент `Users` (во множественном числе) содержит множество элементов `User` (в единственном числе), каждый из которых представляет информацию об одном пользователе. Имена вложенных элементов сокращаем до `Name` и `Pass`, т. к. и так понятно, что они относятся к юзеру.

Названия всех методов и переменных в коде должны хорошо описывать своё предназначение. `XMLRes` - что делает этот метод? Из названия непонятно. Переименуем его, например, в `LoadData`.

Имена `phoneElement`, `companyElement`, `priceElement` вероятно остались от какого-то прежнего кода. Копипаста - зло! Переименуем их.

---

Сделаем класс, который будет содержать информацию о юзере. Таким образом данные об имени и пароле хранятся в одном объекте.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

Для хранения данных о пользователях сделаем поле:

```
private List<User> _users = new List<User>();
```

---

Код загрузки и привязки данных:

```
void LoadData()
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

    foreach (XElement userElement in xdoc.Element("Users").Elements("User"))
    {
        string name = userElement.Element("Name").Value;
        string pass = userElement.Element("Pass").Value;

        var user = new User { Name = name, Pass = pass };
        _users.Add(user);
    }

    comboBoxUsers.DisplayMember = nameof(User.Name);
    comboBoxUsers.ValueMember = nameof(User.Pass);
    comboBoxUsers.DataSource = _users;

    textBoxPass.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), _users, nameof(User.Pass));
}
```

На основе данных из xml создаём классы User и заносим их в коллекцию.
Делаем привязку этого списка к обоим контролам.
Комбобоксу задаём в `DisplayMember`, что он будет показывать имя пользователя. А в `ValueMember` задаём, какое значение он будет выдавать при выборе строки.

Текстбоксу задаём привязку, по которой он будет показывать свойство `Pass`.

---

Вместо парсинга xml с помощью LINQ можно применить десериализацию. Но в данном случае это не имеет большого смысла, т. к. код и так лаконичен.

Вместо `List<User>`, возможно, следует испоьзовать `BindingList<User>` - при добавлении данных в эту коллекцию будет автоматически обновляться GUI.

Comment: Да. Это действительно так. Человеческое вам спасибо

Comment: Десериализацию стоит показать, для будущих посетителей. А то будет "копипаста зло". В общем случае десереализация удобнее, проще и универсальнее, поддерживать код легче. Здесь конечно можно и без нее.