# Записать из документа XML в двумерный массив C#

Tags: c#, xml

Пытаюсь прочитать информацию из ТXML файла, чтобы записать их в двумерный массив C#. По идее, должна быть структура как первый элемент строки - это вопрос, каждый последующий элемент первой строки - варианты ответов.
Помогите, пожалуйста, как это возможно реализовать?
Представил ниже скрин файла XML и моя попытка прочитать файл на C#.

```
        foreach (XmlNode xnode in element)
        {
            if (xnode.Attributes.Count > 0)
            {
                XmlNode attr = xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
                if (attr != null)
                {
                    if (attr.Value == selected)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode childhode in xnode.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            
                            if (childhode.Name == "Questions")
                            {
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```xml
<tests>
    <test name="Документирование как составляющая корпоративного делопроизводства">
        <Questions type="closed1questions">Что понимается под документированием?</Questions>
            <option id="1">Запись (фиксация) информации.</option>
            <option id="2">Ведении документации в соответствии с установленными правилами документации.</option>
            <option id="3">Запись (фиксация) информации, осуществляемая на различных носителях в соответствии с установленными правилами</option>
            <option id="4">Подходят все варианты ответов.</option>
        <Questions type="closed1questions">На что распространяются правила документирования?</Questions>
            <option id="1">На содержание.</option>
            <option id="2">На структуру.</option>
            <option id="3">На стиль изложения.</option>
            <option id="4">На всё вышеперечисленное.</option>
        </test>
</tests>
```

Comment: Да, забыл один закрывающий тег, вроде.

Comment: Ок, теперь он синтаксически верный, а семантически кажется нет, у вас внтури `test` одноуровневая коллекция из разнотипных нод. Отступы пробелами, если что, не влияют на вложенность элементов. Вы сами этот XML создали или он откуда-то пришел? Его можно исправлять? Где здесь правильные ответы, или их не должно здесь быть?

Comment: Сам писал. Только учу эту тему.

Comment: Окей, тогда почему вы выбрали XML, вам принципиально, или можно что-то попроще выбрать ипа JSON?

Comment: Да, по заданию именно нужно XML.

Comment: Ща попробую что-то написать, а вы пока почитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1142336/373567), даст общее представление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работу с данными лучше начинать с объектной модели данных, а не форматирования XML файла. Любую объектную модель легко сериализовать в файл. Это проще сделать, чем сначала нарисовать XML файл, потом после долгих издевательств над ним получить нужную структуру, и потом пытаться сформировать объектную модель.

Рекурсивно читать и писать XML, как и JSON - дело неблагодарное, пусть этим занимаются сериализаторы и десереализаторы.

Модель данных с аттрибутами для XML сериализации

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Tests
{
    [XmlArray("tests")]
    [XmlArrayItem("test")]
    public Test[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("questions")]
    [XmlArrayItem("question")]
    public Question[] Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    [XmlElement("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("answers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("answer")]
    public string[] Answers { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("correct_answer")]
    public int CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь методы записи и чтения из файла для этой модели

```
private static void SaveTests(string fileName, Tests tests)
{
    using StreamWriter sw = new(fileName);
    using XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true });
    XmlSerializer serializer = new(typeof(Tests));
    serializer.Serialize(xw, tests);
}

private static Tests LoadTests(string fileName)
{
    using StreamReader sr = new(fileName);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new(typeof(Tests));
    return (Tests)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
}
```

И вот так давайте протестируем

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Tests tests = new()
    {
        Data = new Test[]
        {
            new Test()
            {
                Name = "Документирование как составляющая корпоративного делопроизводства",
                Questions = new Question[]
                {
                    new Question
                    {
                        Text = "Что понимается под документированием ?",
                        Answers = new string[]
                        {
                            "Запись(фиксация) информации.",
                            "Ведении документации в соответствии с установленными правилами документации.",
                            "Запись(фиксация) информации, осуществляемая на различных носителях в соответствии с установленными правилами",
                            "Подходят все варианты ответов."
                        },
                        CorrectAnswer = 0
                    },
                    new Question
                    {
                        Text = "На что распространяются правила документирования?",
                        Answers = new string[]
                        {
                            "На содержание.",
                            "На структуру.",
                            "На стиль изложения.",
                            "На всё вышеперечисленное."
                        },
                        CorrectAnswer = 3
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    };

    SaveTests("tests.xml", tests);
    Tests tests2 = LoadTests("tests.xml");

    foreach (var test in tests2.Data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Название теста: {test.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var question in test.Questions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Вопрос: {question.Text}");
            Console.WriteLine("Варианты ответов:");
            for (int i = 0; i < question.Answers.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {question.Answers[i]}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Правильный ответ: {question.CorrectAnswer + 1}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в файл **tests.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <tests>
    <test name="Документирование как составляющая корпоративного делопроизводства">
      <questions>
        <question correct_answer="0">
          <text>Что понимается под документированием ?</text>
          <answers>
            <answer>Запись(фиксация) информации.</answer>
            <answer>Ведении документации в соответствии с установленными правилами документации.</answer>
            <answer>Запись(фиксация) информации, осуществляемая на различных носителях в соответствии с установленными правилами</answer>
            <answer>Подходят все варианты ответов.</answer>
          </answers>
        </question>
        <question correct_answer="3">
          <text>На что распространяются правила документирования?</text>
          <answers>
            <answer>На содержание.</answer>
            <answer>На структуру.</answer>
            <answer>На стиль изложения.</answer>
            <answer>На всё вышеперечисленное.</answer>
          </answers>
        </question>
      </questions>
    </test>
  </tests>
</root>
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Название теста: Документирование как составляющая корпоративного делопроизводства

Вопрос: Что понимается под документированием ?
Варианты ответов:
1. Запись(фиксация) информации.
2. Ведении документации в соответствии с установленными правилами документации.
3. Запись(фиксация) информации, осуществляемая на различных носителях в соответствии с установленными правилами
4. Подходят все варианты ответов.
Правильный ответ: 1

Вопрос: На что распространяются правила документирования?
Варианты ответов:
1. На содержание.
2. На структуру.
3. На стиль изложения.
4. На всё вышеперечисленное.
Правильный ответ: 4
```

Если вам нужно редактировать модель в приложении, например добавлять и удалять тесты, вопросы и ответы програмно, можно поменять в модели массивы `T[]` на списки `List<T>`.

Comment: Простите, но я немного затупил в вопросе и не указал, что задание выполняется в Windows Forms. Как можно переделать классы, ибо в WinForms [XmlArray] и ему подобное не работает?

Comment: @MaKFaR не расстраивайте меня. Все там работает, пространства имён подключите. `using System.Xml.*...`. Курсор на атрибут, нажмите Ctrl+. и выберите using.