# Работа с переносом строки (в textBox) в тексте из XML файла c#

Tags: c#, winforms, xml, textbox

Передо мной встала такая задача:

Нужно взять текст из определённого тэга. Данный текст содержит спец символы переноса '\n' и '\t'.

Когда я приравниваю полученный текст к тексту textBox, то он не переносит в нужных местах строки.

Как это реализовать?

Мои попытки были: Записать \r\n в тексте xml; Записать \n\n; Записать * вместо \n и уже в основном коде менять его на \n; Даже просто ставить Enter в XML

Не один из этих способов мне не помог. Что я делаю не так?

Прилагаю отрывок xml кода:

```
    <glava name ="glava2">
        <zagolovok>Заголовок</zagolovok>
        <text>Текст\r\nсодержащий перенос строки и табуляции\r\n\t</text>
    </glava>
```

Прилагаю так же отрывок кода присвоения к textBox:

```
                var galva = book.Descendants("glava").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("glava" + Convert.ToString(paje + 1)));
                if (galva != null)
                {
                    // перебираем элементы главы
                    foreach (var el in galva.Elements())
                    {
                        ...
                        if (el.Name == "text")
                        {
                            //Ищем по имени нужный textBox
                            this.Controls.Find("textBox1", true)[0].Text = el.Value;
                        }
                    }
```

Я так же использую динамически созданный textBox

```
        TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
        textBox1.Location = new Point(70, 20);
        textBox1.Multiline = true;
        textBox1.Width = 258;
        textBox1.Height = 45;
        textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.Controls.Add(textBox1);
```

И такой модуль using System.Xml.Linq;
Подскажите пожалуйста как мне сделать так что б перенос и табуляции осуществлялись в textBox

Comment: XML как-то странно обрабатываете - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1378831/373567, используйте сериализацию, и проблемы не будет.

Comment: Данные не храните в контролах - эта история с печальным концом. Храните данные в специльно предназначенной для этого модели классов. Контролы используются для отображения и взаимодействия с пользователем, а не для хранения.

Comment: `textBox1.Text = "Line1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line2" + Environment.NewLine + "Line3";` и это отлично работает во всех браузерах