# Почему индекс выходит за границу массива?

Tags: c#

Читаю XML файл (спасибо, помогли с этим). Но тут возникла проблема. В этом коде постоянно  ошибка, что индекс выходит за границу массива. Разве во втором цикле переменная не должна обнуляться? И как можно это решить?
Заранее, спасибо!

```
 string[] Question1 = new string[1];
 List<List<string>> Answer = new List<List<string>>(); //обьявление списка

for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    {
       Question1[k] = question.Text;
       for (int j = 0; j < question.Answers.Length; j++)
           {
              Answer.Add(new List<string>());
              Answer[k].Add("asd");
              Answer[k][j] = question.Answers[j];
            }
    }
```

Comment: Основной ответ дал. Если расскажете, зачем вам всё это, то подскажу, как сделать правильно. В чем заключается задача, которую вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Я пытаюсь из файла XML загрузить вопросы в одномерный массив, а ответы в двумерный в список, чтобы затем составить тестирование, где бы рандомно выбирались из первого массива вопросы, чтобы тесты не были одинаковыми. При этом в разных вопросах разное количество правильных ответов (где-то один, а где-то несколько, к тому же есть тип вопроса, где нужно только вписать правильный).

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массив `Question1` содержит 1 элемент, и его индекс 0. А `k` у вас принимает значения 0 и 1. При обращении к `Question1[1]` возникает исключение, потому что этого элемента нет в массиве.

Я же давал вам реализацию обхода коллекции здесь: [Записать из документа XML в двумерный массив C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1378808/373567), но что-то пошло явно не так. И зачем вам вот это `List<List<string>>`, если есть нормальная модель данных? Постарайтесь понять как с ней работать, не выдумывайте костыли.

> Я пытаюсь из файла XML загрузить вопросы в одномерный массив, а ответы в двумерный в список, чтобы затем составить тестирование, где бы рандомно выбирались из первого массива вопросы, чтобы тесты не были одинаковыми. При этом в разных вопросах разное количество правильных ответов (где-то один, а где-то несколько, к тому же есть тип вопроса, где нужно только вписать правильный)

Вот для видимости ваша модель данных. Для того чтобы упростить ее чтение, уберу XML аттрибуты, но вы не убирайте.

```
public class Tests
{
    public Test[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Question[] Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string[] Answers { get; set; }
    public int CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

По порядку.

Чтобы получить рандомный вопрос из набора. К примеру, вы прочитали из файла. И хотите работать с нулевым набором тестов. И получить из него рандомый вопрос.

Заведите поле, где будет жить генератор случайных чисел.

```
private readonly Random rnd = new Random();
```

```
Tests tests2 = LoadTests("tests.xml");
Test currentTest = tests2.Data[0];
// случайный вопрос
Question currentQuestion = currentTest.Questions[rnd.Next(currentTest.Questions.Length)];
// название
string text = currentQuestion.Text;
// список его вопросов
string[] answers = currentQuestion.Answers ?? Array.Empty<string>(); // чтобы если null, то не было исключения, а был пустой массив
```

Обратите внимание, что рандом генератор может генерить повторяющиеся числа. Чтобы вопросы не повторялись, их можно [перемешать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0) и потом брать по порядку. Как перемешать элементы массива - примеров реализации много, вы без труда найдете подходящий.

Теперь про вопрос, у которого нет вариантов, а есть только текст правильного ответа. Не заводите такому вопросу вообще варианты ответов, заполните только `CorrectAnswer`. Только ему тип надо поменять на `string`.

```
public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
```

На сериализацию XML это не повлияет.

При вводе ответа просто сравнивайте (предположу, что это Winforms)

```
if (currentQuestion.CorrectAnswer.ToLower() == textBox1.Text.ToLower()) // ToLower - чтобы в любом регистре ответ писать можно было
{
    // ответ правильный
}
```

При таком подходе будет совершенно без разницы, есть у вопроса варианты ответов или нет.

Вы можете только в интерфейсе сделать подсказку типа

```
label1.Text = currentQuestion.Answers?.Length > 0 ? "Выберите правильный ответ" : "Введите правильный ответ";
```

Comment: А я правильно понимаю, что в строке: Test currentTest = tests2.Data[0]; будет выбран самый первый тест, а если я изменю индекс на 1 или дальше, то, соответственно, будет выбираться следующий тест?

Comment: Простите, что так достаю, возможно, тупыми вопросами. Но как-то я в тупике по поводу перемешать массив. Вернее, метод тасования я написал и у него во входных параметрах (string[] arr). Массив ответов туда передаётся без проблем `string[] answers = currentQuestion.Answers; Shuffle(answers)`. Но если я пытаюсь сделать точно также с вопросами `string[] questions = currentTest.Questions`, то выходит ошибка об неявном преобразовании. Как это можно исправить?P.S. Я гуглил, но видно криво и неправильно задавал вопрос, потому что не нашёл ответа.

Comment: @MaKFaR с чего вы взяли, что он `string[]`? внимательно в класс, где он находится, смотрите.