# Замена значения одного тега, значением из другого тега в XMl файле

Tags: python, c#, vba

Подскажите, есть xml файл (много тысяч строк), в нем есть справки по нумерации, в каждой справке есть информация по налогу (в теге **СумИтНалПер**). В примере ниже привел код только для 2справок, с различающимися значениями сумм
Интересует значения **"НалИсчисл"**, **"НалУдерж"**, **"НалПеречисл**". Значения должны быть равны у всех трех сумм.
Можно ли как-нибудь пробежаться по всему файлу, и в НалУдерж и НалПеречисл положить значение из НалИсчисл?

В примере для первой справки это будет:

```
<СумИтНалПер НалИсчисл="1055" НалУдерж="1055" АвансПлатФикс="0" НалПеречисл="1055" НалУдержЛиш="0"/>
```

**Пример:**

```
<СправДох НомСпр="1" НомКорр="00">
                <ПолучДох ИННФЛ="123" Статус="1" ДатаРожд="01.01.1111" Гражд="643">
                    <ФИО Фамилия="Иванов" Имя="Иван" Отчество="Иваныч"/>
                    <УдЛичнФЛ КодУдЛичн="21" СерНомДок="77 777777"/>
                </ПолучДох>
 
                <СведДох Ставка="13">
                    <СумИтНалПер НалИсчисл="1055" НалУдерж="1100" АвансПлатФикс="0" НалПеречисл="1100" НалУдержЛиш="0"/>
                </СведДох>
            </СправДох>
 
            <СправДох НомСпр="2"НомКорр="00">
                <ПолучДох ИННФЛ="345" Статус="1" ДатаРожд="02.02.2222" Гражд="643">
                    <ФИО Фамилия="Тургенев" Имя="Тургений" Отчество="Тургенич"/>
                    <УдЛичнФЛ КодУдЛичн="21" СерНомДок="55 555555"/>
                </ПолучДох>
                <СведДох Ставка="13">
                    <СумИтНалПер НалИсчисл="563" НалУдерж="562" АвансПлатФикс="0" НалПеречисл="563" НалУдержЛиш="1"/>
                </СведДох>
            </СправДох>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142385/373567